# "月/日/年"を"年/月/日"にして欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳

[モデレーター一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)を見て思ったのですが、任命された日付の書き方が`月/日/年`になっています。
これはアメリカの日付の書き方なのですが日本では年が先に来ます。(つまり、`年/月/日`)
これだと日本人の方で違和感を持つ方がいるかもしれません。私はこのサイトが日本人向けのサイトだと思っています。日本人にとっては日本の表記に揃えたほうが使いやすくなると思います。

"月/日/年"を"年/月/日"にして欲しいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

---

To SE Team:

We Japanese usually write a date as `yyyy/mm/dd`, however [this page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shows a date as `mm/dd/yyyy`. Can you change the format? This string is registered in Transifex/Traducir [here](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/2629), but since the date is given from the system we cannot localize it ourselves.

Comment: メモ: string 自体は https://ja.traducir.win/strings/2629 ですが、日時部分は他から与えられているので Traducir / Transifex では修正できないようです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[このページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)が更新され、YYYY/MM/DD 形式でモデレーターが任命された日付が表示されるようになりました。こちらが `JA` の .Netフレームワークで使用されるデフォルトの日付形式であるために選択されました。

Answer (score 5):

日付部分に限らず「英語」と「それ以外の言語」で生じる **語順の違いが考慮されていない** 箇所が多々あります。

例えば、移行関連の通知でも現状では以下の通り英語の語順に合わせたものになっているので不自然です。

```
Migrated Last month.
~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~
   $1        $2

移行済み 先月
~~~~~~~ ~~~~
  $1     $2
```

期待する日本語での表示は以下の通り (変数の順番を入れ替える必要がある)。

```
先月 移行済み。
~~~~ ~~~~~~~~
 $2     $1
```

**英語での表示**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**日本語での表示**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

他にも「to ～」「～に対して」、「by ～」「～によって」等。